# Python Logging for custom module

Tags: python, python-module, python-logging

I am looking to implement custom logging for my module.

The issues i am facing are the setLevel(0) does not disable the logging, and basicConfig(level=0) duplicates the error with default formatting.

My aim is to disable my modules logging by default without affecting the user and allow the user to import logging and my module and just enable the desired log level `logging.getLogger('rapidTk').setLevel(99)`

`rapidTk/__init__.py`

```py
from .rTkLogging import rTkLogger

import logging
logging.setLoggerClass(rTkLogger)
rtklog = logging.getLogger('rapidTk')
rtklog.setLevel(0)
```

`rapidTk/rTkLogger.py`

```py
import logging
RTKLOG = 1
class rTkLogger(logging.Logger):
    logging.addLevelName(RTKLOG, 'rTk_Log')
    def __init__(self, name):
        super(rTkLogger, self).__init__(name)
        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        fmat = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(filename)s(%(lineno)d) - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(fmat)
        hndlr = self.addHandler(handler)
        self.setLevel(0)
    def rtklog(self, msg, *args, **kwargs):
        print(self.getEffectiveLevel(), 'is the effective level')
        if self.getEffectiveLevel() >= RTKLOG and self.isEnabledFor(self.getEffectiveLevel()):
            super()._log(RTKLOG, msg, args, **kwargs)
```

`rapidTk/rTkUtils.py`

```
from functools import wraps
from time import perf_counter
import logging

def time_it(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start = perf_counter()
        fn = func
        rs = fn(*args, **kwargs)
        t = perf_counter()-start
        logging.getLogger('rapidTk').rtkdebug(f'{fn.__name__} finished in {t}')
        return rs
    return wrapper
```

`projects/mypythonscript.py`

```
import logging
#logging.basicConfig(level=10) ## duplicates the log if level is enabled.
import time
from rapidTk import *
from rapidTk.rTkUtils import time_it
#rtklog = logging.getLogger('rapidTk')
#rtklog.setLevel(0) ##makes no changes

@time_it
def runner():
    print("hello")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("World")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    runner()
    print("done")
```

Here are the outputs for each case:

```
output basicConfig(level=10)>>>
>>> 10 is the effective level
>>> 2022-12-01 17:14:57,161 rTk_Debug rTkUtils.py(17) - tester finished in 1.0115269999987504
>>> rTk_Debug:rapidTk:tester finished in 1.0115269999987504
```

```
output setLevel(0)>>>
>>> 30 is the effective level
>>>2022-12-01 17:16:52,528 rTk_Debug rTkUtils.py(17) - tester finished in 0.9971981999988202
```

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to disable logging by default and let users implement their own logging levels, it is similar to how Python packages implement logging - there is a need to use `NullHandler`.

```
import logging
logging.getLogger('foo').addHandler(logging.NullHandler())
```

Source: The [logging Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#configuring-logging-for-a-library) on how to configure logging for a Python library

For your other issues:

- *setLevel(0) does not disable the logging*: I suspect there is **overriding** happening such that the level is overridden by some other configuration
- *basicConfig(level=0) duplicates the error*: There could be **inheritance** happening resulting in duplicated logs, you need to set `propagate` to False

Source: [Common issues](https://towardsdatascience.com/basic-to-advanced-logging-with-python-in-10-minutes-631501339650#9202) faced in logging